# Loves another girl

Tags: relationships, homosexuality

I'm a girl and gt engaged... I love a girl ,she is 10 yrs younger than me. . And we're in love each other.. bt no any physical relationship.. I was read that is ,In Islam ,if one loves another, tell them (boy to boy & girl to girl) .. As an elder sister_younger sister ,can I kiss her ??? I have no younger sister..that's Y ,I see her as ma little sister..in that ways, can I kiss on her forehead,cheeks??? Plz rplyyy...

Answer (score 3):

Considering somebody your sister or brother doesn't change anything in the real relationship. Either a person is by birth or fostering a mahram or becomes one by marriage anything else is just hearsay that is far away from the teaching of Islam.
Note that many people (including parents) consider somebody like family (and were mistaken as this was the first step to unlawful relationships), but as long as this person is a foreigner according the teaching of Islam he/she must be handled as such.

And homosexuality is haraam in Islam.